# how the pointers get the address of variables, arrays, pointers, structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list

Code to my linked list program: [This is the code I saved on github](https://github.com/AbhimanyuAryan/LinkedList-adding-number-in-beginning-/blob/master/Source%20Code)

Knowing that pointers always accept the address of a variable. So if someone is writing just the name of array means that that is the address of the first element of the array. Ok that is right that's the address so we need not write an `&` in front of the array name. But if it were any other thing then we had to use the `&` sign. So in case of `int` we write that `&` sign in front of it. But what in the case of structure that is also a kind of variable of some custom made size?

The code for array may look like this:

```
int arr[] = {34,234,6234,346,2345,23};
int i;
for(i=0; i<(sizeof(arr)/arr); i++) 
     int *pointer = arr+i; //Now pointer can point to all the member array one by one
```

The code for an int may look like this:

```
int a = 5; 
int *pointer = &a;
```

But if i have two pointers(head & temp) to structure of type `struct node`. Now I am writing the code for node.

```
struct node {
    int data; 
    struct node *next;   // this is pointer to next element in the Linked List
};
```

Now initially head is NULL i.e. not pointing to anything
    head = NULL;

But on the first insertion to the linked list if do this:

```
head = temp;       // both are pointers
```

knowing that head can only take the address coz its a pointer but temp is not an array so if write this writing temp doesn't mean its the address of that structure temp

Should I do this

```
head = &temp
```

to actually get the address of that temp structure(pointer)?

I get a feeling that we do `head = temp` and that valid cause like arrays `temp` is pointer of type structure node. So writing `temp` means just the address of the temp pointer in the memory. And Now `head` pointer is having the address of `temp` & pointing to what `head` has?

Is `head` pointing to address of `temp` or `head` has now address of temp. Pointing and having are different I guess.

Comment: What does `sizeof(arr)/arr` mean??? You probably want `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)`...

Comment: A pointer is technically an integer value, where the value is the address where the pointer points to. If you want e.g. `head` to point to where `temp` is pointing, straight assignment is what you should do. If you use the address-of operator, you tell `head` to point to the `temp` variable, and not what `temp` points to.

Comment: You seem to be confusing "the address of a thing" and "the address of a different thing". The address of *any* object `x` is always `&x`. That's also true for arrays. But *additionally* the array expression itself decays into a pointer -- but a different kind of pointer! It decays into the pointer to the *first element*. That's a  different animal from the array itself. So both `arr` and `&arr` exist and make sense, they're just different things.

Comment: I think  you confused between address of pointer and address pointed by pointer.

Comment: If you feel, that your question might get misinterpreted or get a too formal answer, bold plus italic font won't change that…

Comment: @Jayesh can you give me link to any video that might help me getting this concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain my comment, see the following crude drawings:

In the case of `head = temp` it will look something like

```
+------+
| temp | --\
+------+    \     +----------------+
             >--> | your structure |
+------+    /     +----------------+
| head | --/
+------+
```

That means that both `head` and `temp` points to the same place.

---

If you on the other hand do `head = &temp` (and the compiler allowed it), it will look like

```
+------+      +------+      +----------------+
| head | ---> | temp | ---> | your structure |
+------+      +------+      +----------------+
```

That is, `head` points to `temp` and not to your structure.

Comment: Whats is my structure in this case @JoachimPileborg ? Struct node ?

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan The actual structure is irrelevant. It doesn't even need to be a structure. I'm just explaining what happens in the two cases.

Answer (score 2):

`head` and `temp` both are of type `struct Node*`. Assigning `temp` to `head` means `head` is pointing to the same location as that of pointed by `temp`. `&temp` is the address of the `temp` variable which is of pointer to `struct NODE` type, i.e `struct Node**`.

`temp` and `&temp` both are of different type. You compiler should raise awarning fo the assignment

```
head = &temp;  // assigning incompatible pointer without cast
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of single variable whether an `int` or `char` the address of operator & is used to reference that variable. In case of an array of integers, the name of the array arr[] i.e arr itself represents the address of the first element of the array. See below how the pointer arithmetic operation arrays internally do:

To reference the 'i'th element we write `arr[i] = *(arr + i)`
So, `arr[0] = *(arr + 0) = *(arr)`

But in your case, `head` and `temp` are pointers of the type `struct node*`. Using & operator to assign the address of temp to head will firstly won't be allowed by the compiler giving a cast error and moreover it will not serve your purpose either. What you should do is `head = temp` which will make `head` and `temp` point to the `struct node`.

Comment: so pointer to array and pointer to pointer are different? I mean if this temp was an array than head would point to aaray & but now its a pointer so head is pointing to whatever temp is pointing to

Comment: Yes they are different, when you declare something like a[3], then 'a' represents the base address of array. but &a is not pointer to pointer int **, instead it is pointer to array of integers, int(*)[]....which is not same as int ** hence the compiler error.